# Is there a way I can add a mouseover event to an image in google script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I'm making an application in google script editor for google slides where when the user hovers over the image, the image enlarges. Q1: Right now I have a onOpen function which calls a hover image function that should for each image on the slide user is selected, adds a mouseover event to each image. I'm having trouble with how to add mouseover event for images? Also is there a more efficent way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to add the events to the images? I don't think it's possible as Apps Script runs the script from the server side.

Comment: Does it need to be on Slides? If its only a matter of zooming in images, perhaps you'd have better ease with a web app.